# Divide userControls events

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I developed a userControl that reacts on the MouseWheel and KeyDown event.

Dragging this userControl multiple times onto the same form I recognized that the problem was that only the first userControl reacts on the MouseWheel and the KeyDown event the others do nothing.

What must I do to solve this problem and each of the controls reacts on the MouseWheel and KeyDown effect even it becomes the focus.

Can anyone please provide a solution in VB.Net or C#?

Comment: It all depends on how you are wireing up your events. Please show post the code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to place each control in one event handler separated by a comma like so:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
' Add event-handler code here.
End Sub
```

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3exstx90(v=vs.110).aspx